# Switching to a remote branch and set up local files

Tags: git, branch

I'm currently trying to deploy an application hosted through github, this application has two branches, master and bleeding. I've cloned the application and show origin does list the remote branch, I've attempted all sorts of checkout commands but they don't update the actual files, pulling does update the files as well - saying they're already up to date, how do I switch to this remote branch and set up the files to be ready to run from the git command line?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to host your web app from GitHub, you'll need to put it on a branch called **gh-pages**. When you have a gh-pages branch in your repository, GitHub will automatically make it available at *[username]*.github.io/*[repo-name]*.

Please clarify further what you're trying to accomplish if I'm not understanding your question correctly.